# How to capture page with google map?

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps

I have a UIComponent with Google map in the continer.
I need to capture this container for making a preview.

My integration looks like the following:

```
 <mx:UIComponent id="mapContainer"
        width="410"
        height="300"
    />


 googleMap = new Map();
 mapContainer.addChild(googleMap);
```

But if I do("this" - is my UIComponent)

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.width, this.height, true, 0x00ffffff);
bmd.draw(this);
```

I see the following:

```
An ActionScript error has occurred:
SecurityError: Error #2123: Security sandbox violation: BitmapData.draw: http://localhost/ cannot access http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@121&hl=en&src=api&x=1&y=1&z=1&s=Gali. No policy files granted access.
    at flash.display::BitmapData/draw()
```

I now, that I can to add it host to allowed on the custom client. But I need to have working system on any computer )

I've tried to hide it:

```
templateGoogleMapRenderer.mapContainer.setVisible(false);
templateGoogleMapRenderer.mapContainer.includeInLayout = false;
```

But it was unsuccessfully.

May be I can override some method in my UIComponent, that flex use during BitmapData/draw() ?

Capture with hidden map is success result for me )

Answer (score 1):

You may need to force the app to check google maps' cross domain policy file before attempting to access the bitmap data. Their cross domain policy file is located here: maps.google.com/crossdomain.xml

You may find this helpful if you're unsure of how to force it to check the cross domain policy file: http://www.abdulqabiz.com/blog/archives/2007/01/28/enabling-bitmapdatadraw-on-crossdomain-images-in-adobe-flash-player-9/

Answer (score 0):

The Google Map Flash API has a method called [`Map.getPrintableBitmap()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/reference.html#Map.getPrintableBitmap).  You won't get sandbox errors if you use this method.  Example code:

```
import flash.display.BitMap;
import flash.display.BitMapData;

var bitmap:Bitmap         = googleMap.getPrintableBitmap();
var bitmapData:BitmapData = bitmap.bitmapData;
```

where `googleMap` is your `com.google.maps.Map` object.